# Does breezy fully replace bzr, in msys2

Tags: bazaar, msys2, breezy

The title tells it all:
**Does `breezy` fully replace `bzr`, at least in msys2?**
E.g., by aliasing.

I found little info on this:
https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/80740

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Breezy is a full replacement for Bazaar. It's derived from the Bazaar codebase, and compatible with the Bazaar command-line interface.

There are a large number of changes to the internal API, but unless you use third-party plugins or use scripts that use the bzrlib API, that should not be relevant to you.

We've also dropped support for a number of older platforms (e.g. Windows '95 and '98). I don't think msys2 was ever explicitly supported as a platform, but we're happy to help fix any issues you may run into. See https://www.breezy-vcs.org/pages/support.html for ways to reach out to us.

You can read more about the rationale for the fork here:

- https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/bazaar/2017q2/076170.html
- https://www.jelmer.uk/breezy-intro.html